TCP stream ends with retransmission of last FIN,ACK packet
The TCP network connection between an Haproxy server in TCP mode (.94) and Postfix (.137) randomly ends with the retransmission of last FIN,ACK packet from the Postfix server:

It only happens for around 25% of the connections, sometimes the Haproxy server delays the reply until receiving the retransmission, as seen before, and other it replies ASAP like this other example:

I tried to tune rto_min on the Postfix server as pointed here to a very large value (2000ms), only to know if the Haproxy server finally reply, but it seems to apply after receiving the ACK, just before the retransmission:

What other options could I check to dig into this issue?
Thanks,

What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Which OS is used for both endpoints?

linux on both sides. Trying to fix the retransmission packet issue.

"... sometimes the Haproxy server delays the reply until receiving the retransmission," - this is one way to interpret it. But it might well be that haproxy would eventually answer, only that the retransmission came before it had the time to answer.

"Trying to fix the retransmission packet issue." - so there is no real impact apart that you don't like the retransmission?
